# How to implement a Symfony auth based application with authentication provider

Tags: authorization, single-sign-on, provider, symfony-2.8

I have an SSO application where apache gives me users. I want to authorize users based on my application defined role and for first request store an user details for administrative permission usuage.

Hence I defined my security.yml as :

```
security:
    providers:
        webservice:
            id: webservice_user_provider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(css|images|js)/
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/.*
            remote_user:
                provider: webservice
```

and the class is as:

```
// src/AppBundle/Security/User/WebserviceUserProvider
class WebserviceUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(Container $container, ObjectManager $em)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * Function loadUserByUsername.
     *
     * @param mixed $username username
     * @param mixed $userName
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($userName)
    {
// I have to check if user exists in browser session and the SSO user is same as session user, hence I am checking 03 scenarios:
         if no session creating user from fresh and store in DB
         if session exists and match with SSO user then do nothing
         if session exists but no match, then destroy session and create user->create session
    }

    /**
     * Function refreshUser.
     *
     * @param UserInterface $user user
     */
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof WebserviceUser) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf(
                    'Instances of "%s" are not supported.', 
                    get_class($user)
                )
            );
        }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername(
            $user->getUsername()
        );
    }
}
```

My question are,

- the way I am doing if its a right approach?
- if any way I can make it
  right?